# Prevent Manual Unsub request to be processed by RMM for transactional sends using custom reply mail management in sender profile

Tags: marketing-cloud, reply-mail-management, transactional-messaging-api

Our client wants to ensure that customer cannot unsub from a Transactional email while they can for Commercial Sends. We have "Unsub Manual Request" marked as yes in RMM settings.

When i go to my transactional sender profile and set up custom reply mail management "Use custom setting below" option is checked, email are forwarded to an actual mailbox. However, when i reply to the transactional email with any Unsub keyword, i still get unsubscribed. Can someone advise how i can make sure that manual unsub for transactional sends are not honored by account level RMM and is totally bypassed.

Edit: If i use direct forwards setting, how should i setup a auto-reply informing customer that they cant be unsubbed from a transactional email sends. Do we have any custom solution for this?

TIA

Comment: Transactional send class doesn't honor unsubscriber status but that doesn't mean subscribers can't unsub

Comment: Thanks @EazyE - looks like this functionality "doesn't honor unsubscriber status " is not working for me. I tested sending an email to an unsubscribed customer and they didnt receive the email.